# How Do I Change a Meteor Template Dynamically?

Tags: templates, meteor, spacebars

Is there a way to change a Meteor Template dynamically with a helper Variable?

Example:

templateChanger.html

```
<template name="templateChanger">
    {{> iWantToChangeThis}}
</template>
```

templateChanger.js

```
Session.set("activeTemplate", "someTemplate");

Template.templateChanger.helpers({
  iWantToChangeThis:function(){

    return Session.get("activeTemplate")

  }
});
```

Desired Result:

{{> someTemplate}} is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template name="templateChanger">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=iWantToChangeThis}}
</template>
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic